# Count strings in Series Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['Ciao, I would like to count the number of occurrences in this text considering negations that can change the meaning of the sentence',
                    "Hello, not number of negations, in this case we need to take care of the negation.",
                    "Hello world, don't number is another case in which where we need to consider negations."]})
```

I would like to count how many times a string appears in those senteces. So I simply do:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(['need'], columns = ['D'])
df['X'].str.count('|'.join(d.append({'D': 'number'}, ignore_index = True).D))

0    1
1    2
2    2
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

However, in the application I am doing, I need to loop over each element of `df` which means:

```
res=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    f = df['X'][i].count('|'.join(d.append({'D': 'number'}, ignore_index = True).D))
    res.append(f)

[0,0,0]
```

I get two different results. The first one is obviously correct.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do a loop because you are looking for negations (not and don't)?

Comment: yes in the real-life application yes. But in the specific case, I'd just be fine if I got the same results as when I don't loop

Comment: For your [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071712/how-to-count-the-number-of-specific-words-in-a-string-conditional-on-negations), I recommend you to contact directly [@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew). I'm sure he can help you!

Comment: @Corralien thanks a lot! I will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iterrows`:

```
import re

words = ['need', 'number']

res = {}
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    count = len(re.findall('|'.join(words), row['X']))
    res[idx] = count
df['count'] = pd.Series(res)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                   X  count
0  Ciao, I would like to count the number of occu...      1
1  Hello, not number of negations, in this case w...      2
2  Hello world, don't number is another case in w...      2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way is to use another function to count number of occurrences in a regex. You can try something like that:

```py
import re
res=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    pattern = '|'.join(d.append({'D': 'number'}, ignore_index = True).D)
    text = df['X'][I]
    count = len(re.findall(pattern, text))
    res.append(count)
```